# Using (sqrt x) in Lisp code

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am having some issue while writing symbolic differentiation in lisp.
I am trying write derivative of sqrt (x) but when i use this variable inside code, it give me that x is not defined.

```
;----------------------------------------
;       deriv sqrt
;----------------------------------------
(defun derivsqrt (expr var)
  (smult (smult (sdiv 1 2) 
                (sqrt (second expr)))  ; This line gives me error
         (deriv (second expr) var)))
```

I am calling this function like:

((eq 'sqrt (first expr))
    (derivsqrt expr var))

and I am testing it with: (deriv '(sqrt (* 3 x)) 'x)

Can somebody help?

Comment: The function seems to assume that `expr` is a list with at least two elements. What are you passing in?

Comment: Why not include the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(second expr)` is the list `(* 3 x)` which is not a number, but the function `sqrt` demands a number for its argument. Since you say you want to do symbolic differentiation, you probably should return a list with the symbol `sqrt` in it, rather than calling the function.